# How to display single scalar value in Telerik Report?

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, telerik-reporting

I need to show a single value in telerik report. I need to pass report parameters to the function that returns this single value and and display that returned value in a textbox in the body of the report.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding a property in the the partial class of the report and assign it to the control in the [`NeedDataSource`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/radgrid-telerik.webcontrols.radgrid-needdatasource_ev.html) event handler.

```
public partial class SimpleReport : Telerik.Reporting.Report
{
    public int ScalerValue;

    private void Report1_NeedDataSource(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         myTextBox.Text = ScalerValue.ToString();
    }
}
```